# Citrix Access Gateway workaround

Tags: vpn, tunnel, citrix

I receive a service from a company that requires me to connect to Citrix Access Gateway while I am working with this service.

While i am connected, I have no access to any network services, local or external (cant access local network printers or the internet). Is there any way to get access to network resources? dual NICs? a routing table? anything?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Probably routing table.  Before connecting, do a Route Print from command line and copy the contents, then loin to the CAG and do a Route Print again.  I'm guessing it sends everything by default to a public IP.  Change the routing table so only that one IP address goes via the route over the virtual Citrix adapter (guessing this is how it would setup) and the rest still goes back to your usual gateway.

I've setup the same thing but for our Juniper VPN.

Answer (score 0):

Citrix actively deletes and changes your routes, so whenever you add a route it ands another route around it.

Does anyone have a workaround for this?